# XGBoost - does it make sense that accuracy decreases as threshold increases?

Tags: python, boosting, accuracy, threshold

I'm using XGBoost for a classification problem, and if I need to check how accuracy changes as a function of threshold. As a result, I got that accuracy decreases as the threshold value increases (see plot below). Does that make sense?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
num_col = df.shape[1]

# split data into X and y
X = df.iloc[:,2:(num_col-1)]
y = df.iloc[:,num_col-1]

# split data into train and test sets
seed = 7
test_size = 0.33

# With the stratified split, we take into account class imbalances. 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101, stratify=y)

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

threshold = []
accuracy = []

for p in tqdm([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95]):
    threshold.append(p)
    y_pred = (model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] >= p).astype(int)
    predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
    accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test,predictions))

plt.scatter(threshold,accuracy)
plt.xlabel("Threshold")
plt.ylabel("Balanced accuracy")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It might, what's the ratio of the two classes?

Comment: The minority class is 1.55% of the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense, as you increase your threshold and apply an arbitrary cutoff to the predicted probabilities you will increasingly classify all units to the majority class (which represents 98.45 % of your data), which is what you see in your plot, the accuracy drops towards 0.9845. If you try a threshold of say 0.999 you should get exactly 0.9845.

Comment: To be sure I understood correctly: the logic is `if probability > threshold, then minority classes. Else, majority class`. Is that correct?

Comment: @albus_c Yes, in this specific case because you coded the classes as such.